# PostgreSQL Functions Export

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql database for my application. I want to take only procedure script backup as .sql file not entire database. Is it possible with postgresql? I am using pgAdmin as UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can dump only the object definitions (which includes the functions) using `pg_dump` with parameter `-s`.

More info here - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: Is it possible to export functions only?